# Parallel.For interruption

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, parallel-extensions

Suppose you have an array of 1000 random integer numbers and you need to loop over it to find the number 68 for example.

Using the new Parallel.For on a quad core CPU would improve speed considerably, making each core to work only 250 array items.

The question is: is it possible to interrupt the Parallel.For loop when the following condition is met?

```
if (integerArray[i] == 68)

   break;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to stop after the current executing iteration are done (but iterations before the current WILL be executed - that is, the iterations with a lower index = i)

```
Parallel.For(0, 100, (i, s) =>
    {
        s.Break();
    });
```

or if you want to stop after the current and interations before this (in terms of index = i) should also stop

```
Parallel.For(0, 100, (i, s) =>
    {
        s.Stop();
    });
```

but in BOTH cases it is good practice to check if the work should be aborted if the iteration can take a while

```
s.ShouldExitCurrentIteration
```

read more here [Parallel.For Method (Int32, Int32, Action(Int32, ParallelLoopState))](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782827.aspx)

Comment: I mixed up some notion about `Break` and `Stop` - please reread the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me that you should look into PLINQ (Parallel LINQ) to execute a parallel query, rather than a parallel for.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx

Comment: Correct for this (simple) example. But it is a more general question.